# ios - retrive selection field in Form by hyperoslo

Tags: ios, swift

Link for [Hyperoslo/Form](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Form#faq) : https://github.com/hyperoslo/Form#faq

```
[
  {
    "id":"group-id",
    "title":"Group title",
    "sections":[
      {
        "id":"section-0",
        "fields":[
          {
            "id":"employment_type",
            "title":"Employment type",
            "type":"select",
            "size":{
              "width":30,
              "height":1
            },
            "values":[
              {
                "id":0,
                "title":"Part time",
                "default":true

              },
              {
                "id":1,
                "title":"Full time"

              }
            ]
          }

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

the above code for design ui by json file. 
I am facing issue on, i am unable to retrive data from **type : "select"** . I need, which option is selected in select field.

Comment: I don't understand what is your issue. You have a JSON object, you know the value that you need to grab, and how to grab values from a JSON object has already been explained *so many times*... So, what is your problem *exactly*, supposing you actually have one?

Answer (score 0):

In your class derived from `FORMViewController` you can try to call the following code:

```
let selectedItemId = self.dataSource.values["employment_type"] as! Int
print(selectedItemId)
```

In console you will see id of selected item (0 or 1 in your case).